# Strict positivity on the diagonal of a particular integral kernel: A question from Simon's Schrödinger Semigroups

Tags: spectral-theory, open-problem, mathematical-physics

This is a question pertaining to a (formerly?) open question from Barry Simon's [Schrödinger Semigroups](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-7/issue-3/Schr%C3%B6dinger-semigroups/bams/1183549767.full). In Theorem C.5.2 (page 504) of that publication, the existence of a specific function $F(x,y;\lambda) = dE(x,y;\lambda)/d\rho$ is proven, which is

> "an integral kernel of the [Radon-Nikodym] derivative of the spectral
> projection"

It is easy to see that $F(x,x;\lambda)\ge 0$ for almost every $\lambda$. On page 510, Simon states the question:

> *Open question.* The following is somewhat related to unique continuation [...]. Is $dE(x,x;\lambda)/d\rho$ a *strictly* positive function for a.e. $\lambda$?

My question is exactly the same: Is this still open? Where would I find out more about this specific function, or about the solutions of "minor open questions" in general?